# Cannot remap Control Backspace and Control Shift Z in Windows

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows

What's up with Control Backspace, and Control Shift Z for the Windows cmd terminal?

I cannot seem to remap them.

All the former does in Insert Mode is type Î, and then make the "z" letter show up in the statusbar.

And bafflingly, in Normal Mode, the latter opens a new instance of cmd within cmd.

In answers to other questions, I saw that VIM does not recognize Shift - or at least, that's the way I understood it.

Well, if it doesn't recognize Shift, then why is my remap of C-Z to Undo not triggered when I press Control Shift Z?

Answer (score 0):

What do your mapping commands look like?

In Ubuntu 18.04LTS, I have a local `ftplugin/test.vim` file where I added:

```
nnoremap <C-Z>  u
inoremap <C-Z>  <ESC>ui
```

I opened up a `tmp.test` file, added text in insert mode, changed to normal mode and pressed `<ctrl>+<shift>+<z>` and the insert mode changes were undone.

Similarly, staying in insertmode and pressing the same key combinations undid the text as well.

If you provide your mappings in your answer, that may help shed some light on the issue.

Comment: I am using the mapping commands from mswin.vim - which I'm sourcing - which are `noremap <C-Z> u` and
`inoremap <C-Z> <C-O>u`. For backspace, I am using `noremap! <C-B> <C-w>`, which apparently has no effect.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using the powershell terminal in windows?  My commands were all done in ubuntu.  I updated my comment to reflect that.

Comment: I am using cmd. The same happens in Powershell, though.

Comment: Is your `mswin.vim` file being sourced properly?  Where I put my test code `test.vim` it will only load those mappings for file types with the `.test` extension.  If your commands are in `mswin.vim`, I *think* they'll only be used in the file type.  Maybe check if that is the problem?  You can just put them in your `.vimrc` instead (or the windows equivalent of that file).

Comment: Or to ask differently, are there other mappings in your `mswin.vim` file that still work and these are the exceptions?

Comment: All my mswin.vim mappings work fine. Putting the mapping commands in _vimrc (which is what I was already doing), but excluding the command to source `mswin.vim`, makes no difference.

Comment: `<C-B>` is **not** CTRL-Backspace. It is  `Ctrl-B`, Backspace would be `<BS>`, but be aware of https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5